# Using A Boolean Method

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm confused as to where and how I should use the "isSolvable" method. I need to use it to check and make sure the denominator is not 0 for obvious reasons. In other words, how do I go about using the "isSolvable" method I have created on variables "x" and "y"?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearEquations {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private double a, b, c, d, e, f = 0;
double x, y;

public double getA () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of a: ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    return a;
}

public double getB () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of b: ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();
    return b;
}

public double getC () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of c: ");
    double c = input.nextDouble();
    return c;
}

public double getD () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of d: ");
    double d = input.nextDouble();
    return d;
}

public double getE () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of e: ");
    double e = input.nextDouble();
    return e;
}

public double getF () {
    System.out.println("Enter the value of f: ");
    double f = input.nextDouble();
    return f;
}

private boolean isSolvable() { 
    if ((a * d) - (b * c) == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public double getX() {
    double x = ((e * d) - (b * f) / (a * d) - (b * c));
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    double y = ((a * f) - (e * c) / (a *d) - (b * c));
    return y;
}

}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Btw you can just use `return ((a * d) - (b * c) != 0)`.

Comment: For one thing, you make sure that the fields `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` are actually assigned.

Comment: What do you mean by assigned? I assigned them to 0, if I'm understanding properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this

```
public double getX() {
    if (isSolvable()) {
        double x = ((e * d) - (b * f) / (a * d) - (b * c));
        return x;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentExceprion();
    }
}
```

Same for `getY()`.

**EDIT**

One example of using this is to catch the exception in the code that uses these methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    LinearEquations le = ...;
    try {
        double x = le.getX();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Equation is not solveable!");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How would I return that the questions is unsolvable with a 0 denominator? I try to do a SOP but it tells me a double can't return a void.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, hope it helps.